# Finding the latex-command for a character

Tags: macros, symbols

How can I write [image] in latex? Which command should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in this particular case, as soon as you know that it's one of those Greek letters, you can look it up and see that it's called "nu" and therefore written `\nu` in LaTeX.

If it's a symbol, try [`texdoc symbols`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

In general, try http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

**Edit**: Sorry, I just followed my own advice and found out that this is more likely to be a `\mathcal{V}`.

Comment: Yes! `\mathcal{V}` (upper case V).

Comment: @Sigur I was lucky this wasn't in some other math font. A bit of context would have helped either way. Anyway, found it :)